# Ionic2 view not updated after FileReader load file

Tags: ionic2, zone, cordova-plugin-file

## The development environment

> cju:~/Projects/ionic2/i2ts $ ionic info
> WARN: ionic.config.js has been deprecated, you can remove it.
> Your system information:
> Cordova CLI: 6.1.1
> Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
> Gulp local:  Local version 3.9.1
> Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.6
> Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.25
> Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.15
> ios-deploy version: 1.8.5
> ios-sim version: 5.0.8
> OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
> Node Version: v4.4.2
> Xcode version: Xcode 7.3 Build version 7D175

## The issue

I tried both on browser platform and ios phone. To see it on browser platform, do the following

> ionic platform add brower
>
> ionic run browser

On the browser, it starts with the "Hello Ionic" page. Click the 'Write to local file using cordova-plugin-file' button, on the back, "This is new text" will be written to a local file using cordova-plugin-file. Click the 'Read from file using cordova-plugin-file' button, the console log shows the file is read back. However, the view is not updated. Click any button again, the view will be updated with the new text.

I googled and found a related issue https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/137. That says FileReader in cordova-plugin-file is not zoned. But I am using "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.6" in my project. Should not it include the fix already. Still I see the same issue 137 in my ionic2 project.

The code is at https://github.com/CharlesJu1/FileReaderNotZoned

Here is the hello-ionic.ts file.

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-angular';

declare var window: any;
declare var LocalFileSystem: any;

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/hello-ionic/hello-ionic.html'
})
export class HelloIonicPage {

  showText: string = 'Initial text string';

  writeText() {
    var newText = 'This is new text';
    function overWriteFile(fileEntry, dataObj) {
      // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry.
      fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

        fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
          fileWriter.seek(0);
          fileWriter.write(dataObj);
        }

        //truncate() will call onwriteend.
        fileWriter.truncate(0);
      });
    }
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {
      console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
      fs.root.getFile("newPersistentFile.txt", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function(fileEntry) {
        console.log("fileEntry is file?" + fileEntry.isFile.toString());
        overWriteFile(fileEntry, newText);
      }, function(error) { });
    }, function(error) { });
  }

  test() {
    var that = this;
    var update = function() {
      that.showText = 'This is test text not from local file';
    }

    setTimeout(update, 1000);
  }

  readText() {
    var that = this;  
    var readFile = function(fileEntry, readFileCb) {

      fileEntry.file(function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {

          //this in the following points to fileEntry.file
          console.log("Successful file read: " + this.result);
          readFileCb(this.result);
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);
      }, () => { console.log('Error reading file ') });
    }

    var readFileCb = function(fileContent: string) {
        that.showText = fileContent;
        console.log('readFileCb: ' + that.showText);
    }

    //check https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file for details
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs) {

      console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
      fs.root.getFile("newPersistentFile.txt", { create: false }, function(fileEntry) {

        console.log("fileEntry is file?" + fileEntry.isFile.toString());
        // fileEntry.name == 'someFile.txt'
        // fileEntry.fullPath == '/someFile.txt'
        readFile(fileEntry, readFileCb);
      }, function(error) { });
    }, function(error) { });
  }
}
```

Here is the hello-ionic.html file.

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title>Hello Ionic</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>


<ion-content padding class="getting-started">
  <p> 
    {{showText}}
  </p>

  <button (click)="writeText()">
  Write to local file using cordova-plugin-file
</button>

<br>
<button (click)="readText()">
  Read from file using cordova-plugin-file
</button>

<button (click)="test()">
  Set the text with a timer
</button>


</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some known issues in beta-5 and beta-6 around Zones.  A new beta should be out soon that resolves them, but in the meantime can you do these steps:

1. Import NgZone
2. Inject instance of NgZone
3. Wrap call where you want data binding to work in the NgZone instance's run method.

See an example here:

https://github.com/danbucholtz/ionic2-weight-tracker/blob/master/app/pages/photo-list/PhotoList.ts#L78

Thanks,
Dan